# Check which instances are currently known by the listener

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jakarta-ee, oracle10g

I am using oracle 10g on windows xp. How can i **"check which instances are currently known by the listener"**? I did googling over it and i found a method of checking, this method says use `lsnrctl services <listener name>` this but when i write `lsnrctl services <LISTENER>` command on command prompt i got "The syntax of command is incorrect" error.

Any idea please? kindly reply.

Comment: Did you try as `lsnrctl services`

Answer (score 1):

You should just type in `lsnrctl services` and in case you know the name just the listenername without the angular brackets like `lsnrctl services xe`

Comment: Thanks for your time.By using lsnrctl services i got following     services summary        services "PLSEXTProc" has 1 instance(s)  ....           does that mean i am having one instance up with name "PLSEXTProc"?

Comment: No ..its not the oracle instance but a service to run some external system commands not entirely sure on that part but its not the oracle database instance for sure

Comment: yes it helped me but i am still in search of finding a method of checking which instances are currently known by the listener.

Comment: @Adnan ok maybe this would help you understand it better, [Read this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/network.101/b10775/listenercfg.htm)